# Create google assistant app with bot framework

Tags: botframework, google-assistant-sdk

Does it make sense to use bot framework for an app on google assistant? is there some documentation around it if it makes sense?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

We haved discussed the matter in depth here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4255

In short, there are no plans for integrating Google Assistant with bot framework as a channel right now but there are third parties solutions on top of Direct Line that allows you to use Bot Framework with actions in Google Assistant.

Comment: I think that is a big strategic mistake. Most clients are asking for that solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this open source bot adapter (bot framework V4):

https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Google

We are using it in combination with the Virtual Assistant template (not the previous bot enterprise template for V4). It works, but we did not include it as a Nuget package, we hauled in the project and made some changes as it was flawed here and there (at the time of writing). Converting Google messages into Bot Framework messages (and the other way around) can be quite tricky.